# Is this a known random process?

Tags: probability

Sequence of $A$s and $B$s is created in the following way: take a random positive integer $n$ with given distribution $p_n$. Put $n$, $A$s and then one $B$ and repeat. So we will have a sequence like $\cdots AAAABABAAB\cdots$.

Is this a known random process?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425292/generalized-coin-problem (and here, "related" is very close to "duplicate")

Comment: The $B's$ don't matter here, they are just place holders.  This is the same as choosing a string of digits from $1$ to $n$.  As you have $n-1$ digits, this is the same as choosing an base $n$ integer uniformly at random up to a certain size.

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming the digits were chosen uniformly.  The problem clearly states that they are chosen according to some (unknown) distribution.  So, then this is some unknown distribution on these integers where each digit satisfies the same distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a *renewal process*.  See the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory).